# How to deploy Angular multilanguage application on Google App Engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, internationalization, angular-i18n

I've built my Angular 8 application, with `angular/cli` and `i18n multilanguage support` (with translations for English, Spanish, French).

So that I can build my app multiple times, one for each language and the build is saved in `dist/my-app/en`, `dist/my-app/es`, `dist/my-app/fr` and so on...

Now I'd like to deploy my app on Google App Engine, but I cannot understand what I should do/configure to deploy all my lang specific versions of my app.

I've already published my default (English) version on GAE and it works, but I don't know how/where to deploy all the other versions (es, fr, etc).

Should I use the dispatch file? What's your best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Any hints? I really have no ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider `dist/my-app` as your root folder regarding AppEngine.

- Add an index.html inside this folder (to redirect to default locale depending on browser preferences or by let user choosing).
- Deploy entire folder as one app in GAE.
- Each localized app will be sub-folders, and then served by GAE as https:///xxxx.appspot.com/en/...

To build multiple application with multiple locales, check [Angular official docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#build-for-multiple-locales).

Each href should be set to locale:

```
"baseHref": "/en/",
```

Then, update `app.yaml` and handlers to serve all sub-folders.

For instance, this should looks like :

```
handlers:
- url: /fr/(.+)
  static_files: app/fr/index.html
  upload: app/fr/index.html
- url: /en/(.+)
  static_files: app/en/index.html
  upload: app/en/index.html
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html
- url: /
  static_files: app/index.html
  upload: app/index.html
```

But I'm not an expert of handlers regexp, so it could be optimized I'm sure.

Deploy folder should looks like :

```
deploy
  app.yaml
  app
    index.html // page to propose user to select locale or auto redirect
    fr
      index.html
      bundles.js...
    en
      index.html
      bundles.js...
```

Comment: Thank you @thierry so inside my dist / Angular folder in my PC I should have all the folders generated by ng build for each language (e.g dist/en, dist/fr, dist/es), then I should configure the app.yaml to deploy to GAE all the dist folder with its subfolder, correct? And then what else? I suppose I should change the base href according to /en, /fr etc ...

Comment: You're right! I've just updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks, in few hours I'll try it and let you known